# ASP.NET MVC 4 - How to route domain.com/blog/2012/12/05/my-friendly-url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to route this:
domain.com/blog/2012/12/05/my-friendly-url

To my blog controller. I'm sure this is easy but I'm having real problems.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Blog-Post",
    "blog/{year}/{month}/{day}/{title}",
    new { controller = "Blog", action = "View" },
    new { year = @"\d{4}", month = @"\d{2}", day = @"\d{2}" }
);
```

the action would then be

```
public ActionResult View(int year, int month, int day, string title) {
```

Comment: That's a regex expression saying four digits. You can write it like `@"\d\d\d\d"` as well. The constraints make sure that the year is four digits, and month and day are two digits respectively. If they're, you'll get a 404. Or did I misunderstand your question?